# Float format in Symfony 2.8 troubles

Tags: symfony, floating-point, formbuilder

I'm getting some trobules whit float type in Symfony. I'll try to explain it.

There any way to setup (config.yml, etc.. or any way) the format of the decimal separator? (comma instead of point, by the way).

If I use number_format in getPrice() of the entity, then, in formbuilder I get an error (expected number), but in twig shows correctly.

I don't want to set number_format in every twig view where i'm ussing this atribute. I'm looking to set a "global configuration" for twig and formbuilder.

Thanks a lot! And sorry about my english!

Comment: @LBA I have read the documentation, obviously. But I didn't found a solution.

Comment: from the link which I provided: "If no formatting options are provided then Twig will use the default formatting options of:" (...) "`$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->getExtension('Twig_Extension_Core')->setNumberFormat(3, '.', ',');`"